# How do I trigger a click on dropdown select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of buttons that act as checkbutton via javascript and checkbutton background images. I'm trying to convert this to a select dropdown list.

I have managed to convert the list with below script: I first move the text inside the a element for it to be a hyperlink, then I wrap the a elements inside select tags and then wrap all of them inside select tags. This creates a nice dropdown - unfortunately this wont trigger the script inside the a element and Im stuck. I cant access the HTML, so it needs to be done with jQuery or Vanilla JS.

```
<div class="column wide”>
    <div class="filterformbox">
        <label>
            <a href="javascript://" name="_ec_pld2_l2" id="_ec_pld2_l2" class="checkboxOn" onmouseup="this.className = (this.className=='checkboxOn'?'checkboxOff':'checkboxOn');" onclick="if( UI.pb_boolean(this, 'click') ) {} return false;"></a>
            Gesorteerd op prijs
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="filterformbox">    
        <label>
            <a href="javascript://" name="_ec_pld2_l1" id="_ec_pld2_l1" class="checkboxOn" onmouseup="this.className = (this.className=='checkboxOn'?'checkboxOff':'checkboxOn');" onclick="if( UI.pb_boolean(this, 'click') ) {} return false;"></a>
            Op voorraad
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
$(".filterformbox label a").each(function() {
    $(this).append(this.nextSibling); 
})
$(".filterformbox label a").wrapAll("<select></select>");
$('.filterformbox a').wrap('<option></option>');
```

Comment: What do you mean with `checkbutton`? Checkbox?

Comment: It's really not clear what you're trying to achieve. Your placing of the `a` element inside an `option` is entirely invalid. Firstly because `a` cannot be a child of `option`, and secondly because you can't have an `option` outside of a `select`. I can only imagine this is working for you because the browser is tidying up the mistakes and adding the required elements for you.

Comment: In the original html the a element has a background image of a checkbox - click on it and it change class as can been seen in the code and it then shows another image of a filled in checkbox. It makes it looks like a checkbox - but isn't really. I however want this to be a dropdown, but  i cant fire the script inside the a element when i select an option in the dropdown.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan Ah maybe it is.. I just want to create a dropdown from that html - but i need to keep the script inside the a element and have them fired when something from the created list is selected. Maybe I went the wrong route here then completely?

Comment: It might be a better idea to give us some more code (and a working jsfiddle), so we have a better idea about what you have now, and what you want to achieve. Also, please answer this comment by adding "@jordumus" to your comment, or I won't get notified. :)

Comment: @Rory McCrossan thanks for the input - I think im way of here.. Maybe I should just change the a elements to option elements and then change the onclick to onchange? Or something in that direction..

Comment: @jordumus heres is a fiddle: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BjPrQm I have made it into a dropdown, but as pointed out by Rory i seems to have done this wrong from the start.